# Creating time series in r software

Tags: r, time-series, frequency

I am trying to create a time series. My data is from 2015-2021 in which each year has 36 observations. My data is not monthly and it is individual data. There are altogether 756 observations.

```
df_new2 <- structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), 
Age = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Race = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Gender = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Life_expectancy = c(71.2, 70.8, 66.9, 62, 
57.1, 52.3)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

library(fpp2)
timeseries <- ts(df_new2[,5], start=c(2015,1), frequency = 108)
plot(timeseries)
```

What should be my frequency?

This is the plot I get.I need the year to be until 2021 but it is until 2040.

[time series plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNgHq.png)

[ts data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN8tT.png)

[ts data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTsT8.png)

Comment: If each year has 36 observations, then your frequency should indeed by 36. `ts` assumes these are equally spaced - if yours are not, this may or may not be an issue. Can you explain in a bit more detail what you are unclear about?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I am getting a plot that does not say much.

Comment: OK, thank you for editing! This is now a good question, especially since you provided an MWE. I will flag this for migration to StackOverflow in the R tag, and once it is migrated and reopened, I will gladly write an answer (unless someone else beats me to it). I am traveling at the moment, so it may be a little while, but I will bookmark this and come back to it.

Comment: Your stated end date, `c(2021,756)`, means the 756th period of year 2021. If the frequency is 36, this is actually the same period as the very last period in 2042 (period 36).  What you see in your plot is just your original 6 points repeated 126 times, to fill up the date range that you requested. You don't actually need to set the end date at all, as long as you've set the start date. Not sure how 7 years at frequency 36 works out to 756 observations though?

Comment: @ChrisHaug Thanks for the explanation. Mine is individual data. So, there are 3 independent categorical variables. Variable race has three categories, variable gender has 2 categories and variable age has 3 categories. I will attach an example of my data here.

Comment: I have added the new plot that I've gotten by changing the frequency. So, the number of observations for 2015 is actually 108 not 36. My problem is this graph does not tell much. My goal is to do forecasting with time series linear regression using tslm () function. But I ended up getting something like this too.

Comment: Hm, I *am* starting to wonder whether this would not be better at CrossValidated, because it really turns out not to be a coding question, but a visualization one... It makes little sense to do a time series plot here, because the observations within each year are not ordered (right?). What I would propose instead: plot seven barplots showing the distribution of Age within each year, another seven for Race, another seven for Gender, plus seven boxplots for the distribution of Life_expectancy. Alternatively, combine some of these variables into mosaic plots that you arrange by year.

Comment: That said, it seems like you bucketized Age. That is usually not good practice, see the discussion here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/1352. Better to use the original ages, and treat them like the Life_expectancy.